# How to calculate NDCG in recommendation system

Tags: python, recommender-system, ndcg

This is a question about NDCG, which is a recommendation evaluation metric.

The following are being used as evaluation indicators for recommendations.

$$DCG = r_1 + \sum\limits_{i=2}^{N}\frac{r_i}{log_2i}$$
$$nDCG = \frac{DCG}{DCG_{perfect}}$$

The code is as follows:

```py
def dcg_score (y_true, y_score, k = 20, gains = "exponential"):
    """Discounted cumulative gain (DCG) at rank k
    Parameters
    ----------
    y_true: array-like, shape = [n_samples]
        Ground truth (true relevance labels).
    y_score: array-like, shape = [n_samples]
        Predicted scores.
    k: int
        Rank.
    gains: str
        Whether gains should be "exponential" (default) or "linear".
    Returns
    -------
    DCG @k: float
    """
    order = np.argsort (y_score) [::-1]
    y_true = np.take (y_true, order [: k])

    if gains == "exponential":
        gains = 2 ** y_true-1
    elif gains == "linear":
        gains = y_true
    else:
        raise ValueError ("Invalid gains option.")

    # highest rank is 1 so +2 instead of +1
    discounts = np.log2 (np.arange (len (y_true)) + 2)
    return np.sum (gains / discounts)

def ndcg_score (y_true, y_score, k = 20, gains = "exponential"):
    """Normalized discounted cumulative gain (NDCG) at rank k
    Parameters
    ----------
    y_true: array-like, shape = [n_samples]
        Ground truth (true relevance labels).
    y_score: array-like, shape = [n_samples]
        Predicted scores.
    k: int
        Rank.
    gains: str
        Whether gains should be "exponential" (default) or "linear".
    Returns
    -------
    NDCG @k: float
    """
    best = dcg_score (y_true, y_true, k, gains)
    actual = dcg_score (y_true, y_score, k, gains)
    return actual / best
```

Assumes k = 5.

At this time, how should NDCG calculate for items that could not be recommended within kth?

For example,

`y_true = [5,4,3,2,1]`

`y_score = [0,0,0,0,0] # 0 means we could not recommend within the top 5`

At this time,

```py
>>> np.argsort ([0,0,0,0]) [::-1]
array ([3, 2, 1, 0])
```

So, following the above code,

NDCG @ 5 = 1.0

This looks strange.

In such a case, should the score be 0 and not be included in the NDCG score calculation?

If you have any references, just showing them is fine with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO,

The fundamental definition of [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain) is that it is a measure of **ranking quality**. This assumes that you have computed the utilities of each document/item and ranked them in a certain order.

With this definition in mind, if you have n-items with **same** utility (which is 0 in your case), computing NDCG to measure the ranking quality within this subset of items (*since you are only looking at items 5, 4, 3, 2 and 1, all of which are not recommended*), will yield you a NDCG score of 1 - since your ranking is perfect if you are only looking at these items.

NDCG is merely a way to quantify the quality of ordering, i.e., **current order** Vs **perfect order** (items sorted w.r.to their utilities). This is meaningless if you are looking ONLY at items with **same** utility score.

I hope this answers your question.